# Setting react state the right way

Tags: reactjs

I learned that you can set state two ways:

1. If it does depend on a previous state value
2. If it does not depend on a previous state value

The second option is fairly easy: just use setState with the properties you want:

```
this.setState({
  name: "John"
});
```

But if it is the first option, you should use setState with a callback. I'm making a flipcoin "game" and here's how i designed its state:

```
this.state = {
  count: 0,
  heads: 0,
  tails: 0,
  currFace: null,
};
```

And here's my "flipCoin" function:

```
  flipCoin() {
    let face = choice(this.props.coin);

    this.setState((currState) => {
      let newState = {
        ...currState,
        currFace: face,
        count: currState.count + 1,
      };
      if (face.includes("heads")) {
        newState.heads += 1;
      } else {
        newState.tails += 1;
      }
      return newState;
    });
  }
```

As far as i know, when you use setState with a callback function, it's like it waits for react to finish updating the state and then returns a new state. Is it correct or my logic is wrong?

Another thing: when i inspected the app with React Dev Tools, when it changed its state, it took a couple of seconds for it to update. I'm not trying to bit brushing or anything, i just thought that it would be "quicker".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous.

Comment: All React state updates are asynchronous, functional update or not. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous Now although this says they *may* be asynchronous, this has pretty much always been the case with updating state.

Comment: Since react always updates state asynchronously I think you need to understand how how the asynchrony and event loop is working in JS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: React state updates are generally very quick, so I suspect it's something in *your* code taking the "extra time". What is `choice(this.props.coin);` doing?

Answer (score 0):

Using callback functions when setting state is about *closure* rather than synchronicity. Consider the following examples:

```js
onClick={() => {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
}}
```

versus this:

```js
onClick={() => {
  this.setState(cur => ({ count: cur.count + 1 }));
  this.setState(cur => ({ count: cur.count + 1 }));
}}
```

Assuming `this.state.count` is `0` start with, this first example will ultimately have `count` at 1 whereas the second example will have `count` at 2. This is because the, in the first case, both state setting functions have closure over `this.state.count` when its value was `0`. In the second case, `cur` will always be the current state, and therefore one of the state setters would bump it up to 1 and the next up to 2.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about the difference between the two, but rather is asking why their specific updates are taking a couple seconds. Seems they understand the dependency on previous state.